# How to ignore whitespace and read from a text file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, file

I am having troubles with the following code.

```
public class ReadFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=null;
        try {
            scan=new Scanner(new File("AllAccInfo.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String input=scan.nextLine();
        while(input!=null) {
            String[] data=input.split("[\\: \t]");
            try {
                input=scan.nextLine();
            }
            catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is my Text File

```
SavingAccount: Sourav Roy Komol 25478963    79863   77010.0 5000.0  45000.0
CurrentAccount: Shami Kaiser    1234789 22167   88000.0 5000.0
```

The Output of the code is

```
Roy
Kaiser
```

I want to pick the the whole name like `Sourav Roy Komol` and `Shami Kaisar` into one String variable. Such that 1st My Programme 1st read the 1st line and pick the "Sourav Roy Komol" will pick the "String x". Same Process same for "Shami Kaisar". How can I pick these values with ignoring whitespace? Here 1234789 and 22167 is also a String variable.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? What you posted does not produce any output (no calls to `System.out.println()`, etc.). The code as posted reads data into `String[] data` but then does nothing with it. From other text above, I gather you must be doing something like `System.out.println(data[2])` somewhere (in order to print "Roy" and "Kaiser") but it's just a guess since the code is incomplete. Post the entire code, please.

Comment: Could you also please post your desired output?

Comment: Sorry for adding the whole code. Actually I forgoted due to 1st question on this platform. 
into the loop I want to print after `String[] data=input.split("[\\: \t]");`
`System.out.println(data[3]);`

Answer (score 0):

Since the input data is tab-delimited (I copy+pasted your input data where each field is separate by a tab), you could easily separate the fields using a [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html). Here's a simple example showing how that could work, using the first line of your input example, and also showing the output when it runs.

```
String one = "SavingAccount: Sourav Roy Komol\t25478963\t79863\t77010.0\t5000.0\t45000.0";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(one, "\t");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println("token: " + tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

And the output here:

```
token: SavingAccount: Sourav Roy Komol
token: 25478963
token: 79863
token: 77010.0
token: 5000.0
token: 45000.0
```

This should be enough of working code to get you going. You will probably want to exclude the "SavingAccount: " part from the first token, leaving just the name ("Sourav Roy Komol"). There are a few options for how you could do that, but the code here should be enough to address your parsing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no full code so I am assuming you are looking for splitting your string so that name will appear as one string.

In that case, you can use below regex in your split & later trim() to remove trailing whitespace:

```
String[] data=input.split("[\\^0-9]");
String name = data[0].trim();  //this will trim trailing whitespace of your returned string.
```

If you print, String `name` in console, you will see full name with trailng whitespace removed. If you want to keep trailing white space, you can ignore doing `trim()` to returned string.

This suggestion assumes that your input file will always have names at first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will only split for one of the three characters you specified. What you should do is to use a capturing group to either split by a colon or a set of white spaces followed by one or more digits. This will give you: the first string before the colon, the name and then each number.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("AllAccInfo.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] data;
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        while (input != null) {
            data = input.split("(:|\\s+(?=\\d+))");
            try {
                System.out.println(data[1].trim());
                input = scan.nextLine();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

###### Output

```
Sourav Roy Komol
Shami Kaiser
```

Comment: Can you explain this `"(:|\\s+(?=\\d+))"`. I dont understand that how it is processed. What is s and why we use 1st bracket, | `?=\\d+` what is the main meaning of it?

Comment: @RishadNadim This is a capturing group, basically you're saying that you want to split either by colon (:) or (|) by a set of white spaces followed by numbers

Comment: you mean this portion to `s+(?=\\d+)` is a set of whitespace?

Comment: \\s+ refers to one or more white spaces, while the bit (?=\\d+) means "followed by a set of digits"

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1**
Assuming you have a plan txt as your database and knows how to get only names from the txt file. Then do this

1. Replace whitespace with underscore
   `st = st.replaceAll("\\s+","_").` This gets all names to have an underscore like this Sourav_Roy_Komol
2. Then when rendering it to the screen
   Do this
   `st = st.replaceAll("_"," ")`, this replaces the underscore with a whitespace.

**Method 2**
Replace  split("[\: \t]") to split("[\s+]");

Hope is clear enough?.

**BASED ON YOUR REQUEST FOR A JSON METHOD: SEE BELOW**
Step 1: Add Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2: Import the library

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Step 3: Create JsonObject.

```
    JSONObject employeeDetails1 = new JSONObject();
    employeeDetails.put("AccountType", "SavingAccount");
    employeeDetails.put("Fullname", "Sourav Roy Komol");
    employeeDetails.put("AccountNumber", "25478963");
    JSONObject employeeObject = new JSONObject(); 
    employeeObject.put("employee", employeeDetails1);
```

Repeat the above code statically for other users OR use loop in filling them up.
Step 4: Add employeesObj to list

```
JSONArray employeeList = new JSONArray();
employeeList.add(employeeObject);
```

Step 5: Write to file

```
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("employees.json")) {
            //We can write any JSONArray or JSONObject instance to the file
            file.write(employeeList.toJSONString()); 
            file.flush();
 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

****NOW!!. The above code ONLY writes data to file (employees.json)in JSON FORMAT**.**
**TO READ THE DATA**

Step 6:

//JSON parser object to parse read file

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("employees.json"))
        {
            //Read JSON file
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
 
            JSONArray employeeList = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(employeeList);//you can delete this line
             
            //Iterate over employee array
            employeeList.forEach( emp -> parseEmployeeObject( (JSONObject) emp ) );
 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Step 7: Create a function to parseobjects

```
private static void parseEmployeeObject(JSONObject employee) 
    {
        //Get employee object in list
        JSONObject employeeObject = (JSONObject) employee.get("employee");
         
        //Get employee fullname
        String fullname= (String) employeeObject.get("fullname");    
        System.out.println(fullname);
        //here you can format the output......
   }
```

Comment: Hey, you should try answering the scenario OP provided instead of making a new one. They could be trying to parse several text files that can't be easily converted to json, for example

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: How can I making a new one which is comfortable for json. Can you tell me the process?

Comment: I have updated my answer to your new request (JSON FORMAT)